# is it possible to use facebook API locally?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can we implement Facebook applications and test it locally ? or we need to upload the script on the server each time we want to test the API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can implement Fb app via localhost. No need to upload them to web server.

Comment: how to register the application ? what is the URL ?